# Read data from DataTable - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I am using ASP.net 4.5 with VB.net. (C# example can also work, I will convert it)

I have the below code that I use to populate a Repeater Control on my form.

```
Private pgdArticles As New PagedDataSource

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        pgdArticles = GetData()
        blogRepeater.DataSource = pgdArticles
        blogRepeater.DataBind()

    End Sub


    Private Function GetData() As PagedDataSource

        Dim pg As New PagedDataSource

        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        conn = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_MyProc", conn)

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dt As New Data.DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        pg.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

        Return pg

    End Function
```

It works fine for using a repeater but I want to read that data and populate labels on my form not using a repeater. Something like below....

My data in my table.................

[image: My data in my table]

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        pgdArticles = GetData()

        If pgdArticles.ID = 1 Then
            lblName1 = pgdArticles.Name 'This will be value Mike
            lblValue1 = pgdArticles.Value 'This will be value 250
        End If

        If pgdArticles.ID = 2 Then
            lblName2 = pgdArticles.Name 'This will be value Ben
            lblValue2 = pgdArticles.Value 'This will be value 400
        End If

    End Sub
```

Is there any other way to do this then? C# or VB.NET code examples will be fine.

Comment: you can use server content control and generate the dynamic html from code behind in place of repeater. for ex div.InnerHtml="<li>name</li>"

Comment: Dont want to use this, I just want to populate different labels located all over the page.

Comment: Why you want this with labels?

Comment: It's the way the HTML is currently build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
Public Property dtArticles As DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    dtArticles = GetData()

    For I As Integer = 0 To dtArticles.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim row As DataRow = dtArticles.Rows(I)
        Dim label As Label = Page.FindControl(String.Format("Name{0}", I))
        label.Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})", row("Name"), row("Value"))
    Next

End Sub

Private Function GetData() As DataTable

    Dim conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_MyProc", conn)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
    da.SelectCommand = cmd

    Dim dt As New Data.DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    Return dt

End Function
```

Html:

```
<asp:Label ID="Name0" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Name1" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Name2" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Please edit your previous answer, don't post another one

Comment: This is not what I want, I need to populate each label with the correct ID and they are not sitting at the same location in the html.

Comment: **Panagiotis**, sorry, I have deleted the first answer. **Etienne**, I have changed the code, please review again.

Comment: Please have a look at your Code section, not folling what you doing there or what the GetData() code needs to look like.

Comment: I have placed back the GetData(), this is your own code besides that I have change the return type to DataTable. Can you follow?

Comment: Yeah! No problem. First points on StackOverflow. New here, but have many years experience in developing.